# Dynamic ImageView in android

Tags: android, imageview

I'm a newbie in android so please don't judge me hard.
I'm trying to create a screen with two areas, an image area and a text area.
In the image area several images should be changed within a periodical time, 3-4 seconds. (Please see the image: [image])

Can you please give me an example how can I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) class for this.

Or you can use a Gallery with Thread and Handler to achieve this.

Here is a link to the project called AutoSlideGallery,

https://github.com/nixit28/AutoSlideGallery

The core logic is here,

```
(new Thread() {

        public void run() {

            myslideshow();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 2000); // execute every two second.
        }
    }
    ).start();
```

And the method which performs the action,

```
private void myslideshow() {
    PicPosition = gallery.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;
    if (PicPosition >= pics.length)
        gallery.setSelection(0); // stop
    else
        gallery.setSelection(PicPosition);// move to the next gallery
                                            // element.
}
```